# Joining two dataframes having same one column and need to merge records for that same column and join other columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, join, pyspark

need to join two dataframes and create a single table.

Issue is one table has UID column which is similar to other tables column UID1 and UID2,In output table need only one column as UID which should have all values of UID, UID1 and UID2 under UID column only

Refer table below :

[IP tables along with desired output table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svuOj.jpg)

Tried using join method of pyspark dataframe but getting multiple UID columns as output

Can someone help with the best possible solution??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the right columns, rename them and then concatenate all together like so:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Tbl1Id': [1], "UID": ['d72777']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [423], "Tbl1Id": [1], "UID": ['z1234'], "UID2": ["x4356"]})

df = pd.concat(objs=[df1[['Tbl1Id', 'UID']].rename(columns={'Tbl1Id': 'PK'}), 
                     df2[['ID', 'UID']].rename(columns={'ID': 'PK'}),
                     df2[['ID', 'UID2']].rename(columns={'ID': 'PK', 'UID2': 'UID'})]).reset_index().drop(columns=['index'])
```

Result:

```
    PK     UID
0    1  d72777
1  423   z1234
2  423   x4356
```

Please do not post pictures of data. I had to type over from you picture, which is error prone.

Comment: I have already tried this medthod, but the issue here is only the UID column has to be concatenated in the new dataframe while other columns of both dataframes are different , if I will try concatenating the two dataframes it will create duplicacy

Comment: Then I don’t understand what you are trying to achieve. Is this not an exact replica of your desired outcome? Otherwise, please provide clear input dataframes and desired outcome (no pictures! )